# Magento Undefined index: url

Tags: email, templates, magento, indexing, undefined

I got an error in my Magento 1.5.1 installation, that I don't know how to track down.

It says: "undefined index: url in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php on line 283"

I checked all email templates, but everything seems ok. Even with all email templates removed, the error still comes up.

Any hints on that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, what does `Filter.php` say in line 283?

Comment: it says `return Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $params['url'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which means there is the `url` key missing in `$params` and `$construction[2]` when calling `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::mediaDirective()`.

My guess would be that you got some CMS block, email template, translation .csv file, etc. using a `mediaDirective` which fails to assign its `url` value correctly.

Scan your files for

```
{{media url=
```

occurrences to see, which one fails to assign its `url`.

A proper one looks similiar to this:

```
{{media url="path/to/image.jpg"}}
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, it was in one CMS block. There was some img src like `{{media url}}/image.jpg`, which showed the image on the page, but did throw this debug message.